# GA4 Engagement rate is zero when adding custom dimension to the report

Tags: analytics, google-analytics-4, custom-dimensions

I'm using custom dimensions in my GA4. GA4 works fine when there are predefined dimensions.

For example, Here I have used **Date** which is a predefined dimension provided by GA4.

[report with predefined dimension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKGUQ.png)

When I use a custom dimension: **Is site** to it, report changes in the following way:

Custom dimension is scoped to "Event"

[report with custom dimension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noOwJ.png)

For some reason **User engagement** and **Average engagement time** do work. **Engagement rate**, and **Bounce Rate** are all zeroed out (the bounce rate is 100%, but that just indicates the 0% engagement rate).

I am expecting the **Engagement rate and Bounce rate** to be bound by the custom dimensions. Could anyone tell me what am I missing here? Thank you in advance.